# delete item by date in mongodb using php

Tags: php, mongodb, date

I need to delete a mongodb element using php based on the date of the element 
When i fetch the Date of the element without any formatting or conversion i get this as an output

> 0.52400000

I dont know which format this is but by using

> date('Y-m-dH:i:s', $post["Date"]->sec)

this function i convert the date to human readable format which gives me something like this

> 2017-05-1210:23:022017-05-1210:38:102017-05-1210:24:58

now based on this value i want to delete an item in the mongodb collection... i.e that specific item which is having this timestamp..

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: No as i don't know which value i should pass in


db.collection.remove({Date: "???"});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$date = new MongoDate(strtotime("2017-05-12 10:24:58"));
$collection->remove(array('Date' => $date));
```

Please refer these links - [MongoDate](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodate.php) and [mongodb remove elements](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.remove.php). And use MongoDate class all the time. Otherwise there can be conflicts.

**EDIT**
You can get your date objects' getTimestamp() insteads of strtotime("2017-05-12 10:24:58")

Comment: but can a variable say $date be passed to strtotime function?

Comment: Sagar, strtotime as name implies, it accept a string and convert to a timestamp value( int). You can pass a variable with value is a  time in string.

Comment: Ya actually i was getting an error and i thought it was due to passing variable but now its done... thank you  soo much